# Octave variable definition error

Tags: function, octave

I'm trying to generate Blackman-Harris window coefficients in Octave. I have declared a function in a .m file like so:

```
function result = BlackmanHarris(window_size)
  a0 = 0.35875
  a1 = 0.48829
  a2 = 0.14128
  a3 = 0.01168
  result = [0:window_size - 1];

  if(nargin != 1)
    print_usage("BlackmanHarris(int window_size)");
  endif

  if(isinteger(window_size))
    for n = 0:window_size - 1
      result(n) = a0 - (a1 * cos((2 * pi * n)/(window_size - 1))) + (a2 * cos((4 * pi * n)/(window_size - 1))) - (a3 * cos((6 * pi * n)/(window_size - 1)));
    endfor
  else
    error("BlackmanHarris: Expecting integer argument.");
  endif
endfunction
```

When I attempt to run this, I get the error:

```
>> window = BlackmanHarris(window_size);
error: 'a0' undefined near line 15 column 16
error: called from
    BlackmanHarris at line 15 column 14
```

I have tried declaring the variables as 'global' and 'persistent', nether of which solve this issue. I'm sure I'm just doing something slightly wrong, but Google has yielded little help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know about your original error but you are trying to use 0 as an index in the calculation of `result(n)`, use `result(n+1)` instead

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Thank you, that was the issue. My bad!

Comment: If that was the issue, then your question is wrong. The error message would be something like `subscript indices must be either positive integers...` and not `a0 undefined...`. The error message you got, if your function is indeed the one on your question, is because you are calling some other function by accident since that one obviously defines `a0` right at the start.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sardar_Usama said, I was attempting to access element 0 of the result array, which of course will not work.

Changing that to n+1 fixed the issue.

Comment: This can't be the answer to your original question where you said the error message is "error: 'a0' undefined near line 15 column 16"

Comment: All I can tell you is that was the error I was getting, and once I changed my script to account for the n + 1 error, it began working... I don't understand it either but that fixed it...

Comment: If you undo you change (replace n+1 with n) do you see the original error again?